# What does $this mean in the context of view files in cake php

Tags: php, html, cakephp

When $this is used in a .ctp file in cakePHP, what does $this refer to? 
First I thought it should be the controller object which is calling that particular view. But in some tutorials, $this->html is used in many .ctp files. But I can't find a property named html in controller class. Therefore $this cannot be referring to the controller class. Then what does it actually refer to?

Please note that I am a beginner in cakePHP.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that I am a beginner in cakePHP.

This sounds more like you're a beginner in php. [Have a read about OOP in php](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.php).

Simply debug an object if you're not sure about what it is:

```
debug(get_class($this));
```

[And see what it will show.](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/class-Cake.View.View.html) And the helpers like the HtmlHelper are accessed through magic [__get()](http://api.cakephp.org/3.0/source-class-Cake.View.View.html#723-737).

I would recommend you to read the source of the framework and its documentation, this way you can learn a lot more than through tutorials because you get a deeper understanding of the framework and you'll learn something about OOP in php.

> But in some tutorials

What tutorials? I would say [stick to the official documentation for the first steps](http://book.cakephp.org/3.0/en/index.html). Tutorials in the wild aren't always the best you can get. The official book explains pretty detailed how MVC works in CakePHP.